# Total number of different permutations of an array in which relative order of elements in two disjoint sub-arrays remain constant

Tags: arrays, permutation

Give an array of integers.

For example a = {1,2,20,19}
Let two disjoint sub-arrays be {1,2} and {20,19}. There are 5 such permutations in which '1' always comes before '2' and '20' always comes before '19' and such are:

1. {1, 2, 20, 19}
2. {1, 20, 2, 19}
3. {1, 20, 19, 2}
4. {20, 1, 19, 2}
5. {20, 19, 1, 2}

My question is:

**Given an array, a[1...n+m] of size=n+m. Find the number of permutations in which relative order of elements in two sub-arrays a[1..n] and a[n+1..n+m] remains the same.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your example it will be 6 permutations. You've missed the {20,1,2,19}.
2. It is a pure math(combinatorics) question. The question is equivalent to -
   find the number of all possible solutions of the equation :

   `x0+x1+....+xn = m`

The answer is defined by the formula - `(n+m)!/(m!n!)`

For example in your case it will be `n=m=2` and the answer is `4!/2!2! = 6`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have `m+n` empty positions. You have to fill these positions such that the relative ordering is correct.

1. Choose `n` positions. The number of ways to choose `n` positions is `(m+n)!/n!m!`.
2. Now there is only one way to fill the elements of the subarray1 to those `n` locations such that the relative ordering is preserved.
3. The rest `m` positions are empty. There is only one way to place the elements from subarray2 to the rest m positions such that relative ordering is preserved.

Hence the final answer becomes `(m+n)!/m!n!`.